# JAVA ArrayList : How to know whether it contains a String array or not?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;    
public class Test {
        public static void main (String[] args){
            ArrayList<String[]> a = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            a.add(new String[]{"one", "abc"});
            a.add(new String[]{"two", "def"});
            if(a.contains(new String[]{"one", "abc"})){
                System.out.println(true);
            }else{
                System.out.println(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Console said "false."
I have an ArrayList and I can't check whether it contains a particular String array.
How to do and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contains` checks object equality using the `equals` method implementation. For arrays, however, `equals` is equivalent to reference equality. I.e. `array1.equals(array2)` translates to `array1 == array2`.

In the above, the `new String[]{"one", "abc"})` passed to the `contains` method will create a *new* array which will be different than the one originally added to the `ArrayList`.

One way to do the check is to loop over each array in the `ArrayList` and check the equality using `Arrays.equals(array1, array2)`:

```
for(String[] arr : a) {
        if(Arrays.equals(arr, new String[]{"one", "abc"})) {
            System.out.println(true);
            break;
        }
}
```

Another way is to use [`ArrayUtils.isEquals`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) from Apache `commons-lang`.

Comment: so how to do? change `contains` to `equals`, the result is still "false".  I need to check if the ArrayList "has" the String Array

Comment: @JeanYang updated my answer. Again you can't call `equals` on arrays as it checks the reference equality, not the object equality.